# How to check CSRF in an ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to add an `AntiForgeryToken` in actionlink, I have a CRUD table and I need to check the CSRF in the delete button how can i do it ? or please to suggest any other way.

```
 Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Home", new { id = row.id}
```

for the creation it's easy since i'm submitting the data, so i'm doing it like this

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult AddUser(UserModel req)
```

and in the view it's like this  :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddUser", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "newUser", @role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
```

thanks,

Comment: You can prevent using the `custom attribute` need to create one Action filter attribute.

Comment: @jishansiddique please give me an example

Comment: In most of the case if we are preventing `get` method using own logic https://blog.elmah.io/cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-with-asp-net-core-and-ajax/   

https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/12/22/csrf-protection-by-default-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: you can try ajax all to controller action method and secure request - https://geeksarray.com/blog/jquery-ajax-autocomplete-in-asp-net-mvc-core